# How use RestKit 2.X in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, restkit, restkit-0.20

I'm new using RestKit, but I can't understand at all how it works...
please, can somewhere explain me it??

My Json file is:

```
    {
    "colors":
    {
        "red":"#f00",
        "green":"#0f0",
        "blue":"#00f",
        "cyan":"#0ff",
        "magenta":"#f0f",
        "yellow":"#ff0",
        "black":"#000"
    }
}
```

and the path where i'm hosting this file is: `http://186.36.181.116/tesis/file.json`

The code that I'm trying in my ViewDidLoad method is:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[colores class]];
    [mapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"colors"]];
    NSIndexSet *statusCodes = RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful); // Anything in 2xx
    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:mapping method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern:@"/tesis/:coloresID" keyPath:@"colors" statusCodes:statusCodes];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://186.36.181.116/tesis/file.json"]];
    RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [[RKObjectRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request responseDescriptors:@[responseDescriptor]];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *result) {
        colores *colores = [result firstObject];
        NSLog(@"Mapped the article: %@", colores);
    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Failed with error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }];
    [operation start];
}
```

My Class "colores" is as follow:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface colores : NSObject{}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSString *colores;
@end
```

Thank you so much in advance!!

Comment: Based on your JSON and URL, the mapping and response descriptors are wrong / don't match. Trying to map a dictionary of key/value pairs to a set of objects also requires special handling because the keys are all arbitrary (unless they are static). I suggest you start with an easier bit of JSON and work up to this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can find a detailed tutorial [here](http://www.alexedge.co.uk/blog/2013/03/08/introduction-restkit-0-20/) and full source code [github](https://github.com/alexanderedge/RestKitTutorial1).

In order to properly map responses to JSON, we must do the following things:

*Create an instance of RKEntityMapping for each entity in our managed object model
*Add mappings between JSON response keys and object properties
*Add mappings between embedded JSON objects and relationships
*Create response descriptors with the mappings
*Optional: Create request descriptors with the mappings if you plan to PUT or POST

Comment: Thanks, well I'll read, but wanted to try to run the code above, but thanks.